# what if user register email address with email typo?

Tags: registration, email, user-communication

we have registration process and we really need for user to confirm their email, we are thinking about:

1. asking the email and password to create their password
2. Next screen, we show the user must confirm their email address to login, with verification code.

[image]

but i am concern, if user typo about their email should i just add wording" change email" like this? [image]

Answer (score 2):

You could duplicate the field for email on the registration form (so that the user has to confirm the email), just like with passwords.

```
Username
[___________]

Name 
[________________]

Last Name
[________________]

Mail
[_____________________]

Mail (confirm)
[_____________________]

Password
[__________________]

Password (confirm)
[__________________]

[SUBMIT]
```

If that doesn't convince you, I could sugest adding the link to change the email next to the one that says resend...

```
ACCOUNT VERIFICATION
You will receive an email with a confirmation code at:
example@mail.com

Haven't reveived it yet? [resend] [change email]
```

Hope it helps ;D

Comment: i read in here https://joshwayne.com/do-you-need-a-confirm-email-field/ that user tend to copy their email if form asked to confirm email address. I also think the second choice approach better communication to user : D

Comment: That seems quite interesting, I will give it a look. Thanks for sharing, no doubt it will be useful :D

Comment: @vsn I used to nearly always copy-paste between the email and verification fields... until I _did_ (mis)confirm an address with a typo. In that case, I just repeated the registration screen (and now try to manually re-enter the address unless I've copied it from a "known good" source).